# Firestore: scheduled export

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have used the code from the Firebase documentation to schedule a backup of the data in my Firestore project in a bucket every 6 hours. See the link and the code here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

// Replace BUCKET_NAME
const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME';

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = functions.pubsub
                                            .schedule('every 24 hours')
                                            .onRun((context) => {

  const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
  const databaseName = 
    client.databasePath(projectId, '(default)');

  return client.exportDocuments({
    name: databaseName,
    outputUriPrefix: bucket,
    // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
    // or set to a list of collection IDs to export,
    // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
    collectionIds: []
    })
  .then(responses => {
    const response = responses[0];
    console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error('Export operation failed');
  });
});
```

Everything works well, my data is saved like I want to but nevertheless I am getting an error:

> Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Can someone tell me what I should change? Would be glad to get a hint.

Comment: This error happens when JSON.stringify() detects a cyclical object, meaning a self-referencing Javascript object to JSON. If you have an object with a circular reference and attempt to convert it to JSON, it is most likely to happen. JSON Format doesn't support object references, thus a TypeError will be thrown, you can check detailed details here. Could you like to share the complete error trace? https://thecodebarbarian.com/the-80-20-guide-to-json-stringify-in-javascript.html